# Is there an official recommendation from Block One about how to install EOSIO?

Tags: nodeos

The docs state the Docker image is not maintained -
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/v1.7.0/docs/introduction

> The Docker image is no longer maintained has been deprecated. The
>   eosio/eos image from Dockehub will be available until it's sunset on
>   June 29 2018

I had seen before that docker should be used.

Is there an official recommendation from Block One about how to install EOSIO?

Answer (score 1):

Final answer - hub.docker.com/r/eosio/eos -

> This image is now deprecated. Future builds will discontinue on
>   January 1st, 2019. This image will be removed on June 1st, 2019.